# How to hide ul element if li's will not be added in the loop

Tags: php, foreach

How to hidden if ul has not foreach content?

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <?php foreach($products2 as $prod2) : { ?>
         ...
  <?php } endforeach; ?>    
    </ul>
```

Full code with addon < ?php if(!empty($products2)): ?>, but will display all li in every parent li

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  ....

  <?php if(!empty($products2)): ?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php foreach($products2 as $prod2) :
        if($prod2['ProductCategory']['parent_id'] == $prod['ProductCategory']['id']) ?>
          <li><?php echo $this->Html->link($prod2['ProductCategory']['name'], array(
                              'controller' => 'products',
                              'action' => 'listing',
                              'id' => $prod2['ProductCategory']['id'],
                              'slug' => Inflector::Slug($prod2['ProductCategory']['name'], '-')
                              )); ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </ul>
  <?php endif;?>

</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just don't print it if the array is empty:

```
<?php if(!empty($products2)):?>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <?php foreach($products2 as $prod2):  ?>
         ...
  <?php endforeach; ?>    
 </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Also, remove the brackets if you're using the short syntax for foreach.

Comment: Thank you, but li will duplicate appear after removed the brackets.